# how to compare datetime using psycopg2 in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-11

I wish to execute the statement  to delete records from a postgresql table older than 45 days in my python script as below:

Consider only the code  below:

```
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime

cur = conn.cursor()
mpath = None
sql1 = cur.execute(
    "Delete from table1 where mdatetime < datetime.today() - interval '45 days'")
```

This causes the following error:

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName: schema "datetime" does not exist
> LINE 1: Delete from logsearch_maillogs2 where mdatetime <
> datetime.t...

How do I exactly change the format or resolve this. Do I need to convert. Saw a few posts which say that postgresql DateTime doesn't exist in PostgreSQL etc, but didn't find exact code to resolve this issue. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

The query is running in Postgres not Python you need to use SQL timestamp function not Python ones if you are writing a hard coded string. So `datetime.today()` --> `now()` per [Current Date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

```
sql1 = cur.execute(
    "Delete from table1 where mdatetime < now() - interval '45 days'")
```

Or you need to use parameters per here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to pass in a Python `datetime` if you want a dynamic query.

```
sql1 = cur.execute(
    "Delete from table1 where mdatetime < %s - interval '45 days'", [datetime.today()])
```